# Colored rectangle under item

Tags: tikz-pgf, texshop

In a latex document I want to add points a question. I am using item to write question number. And on the next line I want to have a colored rectangle with points of a question.

Comment: It is odd to suggest, without seeing `MWE`, please provide the same...

Comment: @Guest Could you please eventually have a look at [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/172164) It really would make it easier for others to help you with your questions (at the same time improving this site's value as a collection of references).

Answer (score 2):

You can just overlay a `tikz` picture after your `\item`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=3ex}

\newcommand{\points}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, outer sep=0pt]
    \node [anchor=south east, yshift=-\baselineskip-1ex, draw, cyan,
      font=\sffamily\footnotesize] at (-\labelsep,0) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item\points{3} A question.
  \item\points{20} Another question.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item\points{4} A question.
      \item\points{5} Another question.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]